# Wifi adapter not found by ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers

Here is the output from the command `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:6203134000-6203137fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 15
       serial: 04:7c:16:3a:9d:95
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-69-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.196 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:76204000-76204fff memory:76200000-76203fff
```

I tried some things, but my wifi adapter still not found

Comment: You could try to install the `iwlwifi` driver with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms` from a terminal.

Comment: Tnx a lot! It worked.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @Dan, **welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** If the problem was resolved, please mark the answer as resolved. Thanks